# phpMyAdmin cannot running after editing .env document

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa6ss.png)When I tried to get in phpmyadmin page this is what I got. After edit .env document in visual studio code with db_name and php artisan config:clear. Before this action, phpMyAdmin is running as usual.[phpMyAdmin fatal error][2]

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, the error message seems to me like part of the phpMyAdmin installation got corrupted or removed. The actions you took should have had nothing to do with phpMyAdmin at all. Does XAMPP give an option to repair an installation? Since this is part of XAMPP, you should repair or reinstall XAMPP itself (being careful not to delete any existing data).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.